# incompatibility between crop and minted packages?

Tags: minted, crop, cropmarks, texlive2022

I'm having problems when using both the `crop` package (for adding crop marks) and the `minted` package (for syntax highlighting of code). Just the loading of the two packages causes `pdflatex` to hang. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% cross and cam options seems to be the problem
\usepackage[cam]{crop}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
Testing, 1, 2, 3.
\end{document}
```

If I drop either the minted usepackage or the crop usepackage, the example typesets fine. But with both in place in either order, the typesetting hangs, and I have to interrupt it with `^c` as shown below.

```shell
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/crop/crop.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetexconfig/crop.cfg))
(/Users/shieber/Library/texmf/tex/latex/minted.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty))
(./test.w18))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(./_minted-test/default.pygstyle)/Users/shieber/.pyenv/shims/pygmentize

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(./_minted-test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)^C
! Interruption.
\CROP@@info ...fter \csname \CROP@font \endcsname 
                                                  {``\jobname ''\x \the \yea...
l.7 \end{document}
                  
? ^D
! Emergency stop.
\CROP@@info ...fter \csname \CROP@font \endcsname 
                                                  {``\jobname ''\x \the \yea...
l.7 \end{document}
                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
%
```

The problem only occurs with certain settings of the crop package, in particular, with  the cross or cam options (and perhaps others). I noted this problem only upon updating TeXLive to the 2022 release. I had no problem under 2017.

For reference, I'm using Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 of pdftex within the TeX Live 2022 release.

```shell
% pdflatex -version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

Any insights as to what's causing this problem greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get a normal run with texlive22

Comment: You are using a non standard `minted`: `/Users/shieber/Library/texmf/tex/latex/minted.sty`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's exactly it. For some reason, I had an old version of `minted` in my local area, which was presumably incompatible with other aspects of the TeX Live 2022 distribution. Eliminating that version solved the problem. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can credit it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a non standard minted:

```
/Users/shieber/Library/texmf/tex/latex/minted.sty
```

remove that, and allow the one from texlive 2022 to be used